# How to make a string preprocessor definition from command-line in VC 2005 (C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, c-preprocessor

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx) tells me that /D command-line switch can be used to do this, like so:

```
  CL /DDEBUG TEST.C
```

would define a DEBUG symbol, and

```
  CL /DDEBUG=2 TEST.C
```

would give it the value 2.
But what do I do if I would like to get the equivalent of a string define, such as

```
  #define DEBUG "abc"
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to the way command line is parsed in Windows, you'll have to escape the quotes.

```
CL /DDEBUG=\"abc\" TEST.C
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in VS2013:

```
/D_STRING="\"abc\""
```

then it is equivalent to

```
#define _STRING "abc"
```

Note, if you do

```
/D_STRING="abc"
```

It will be equivalent to

```
#define _STRING abc
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
CL /DDEBUG=abc TEST.C
```

or

```
CL /DDEBUG="abc" TEST.C
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Glen, the second one could work on the command line, but the coworker I've asked this for eventually used this in the project definition (needing to escape the double-quotes and replace = with #):

```
/DDEBUG#\"abc\"
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have VC to test this for you, however, in principle the following should work:

```
CL /DSTRINGIFY(X)=#X /DDEBUG=STRINGIFY(abc) TEST.C
```

Update:

As highlighted by Kuber-Ober, VC doesn't seem to do the right thing here.  Testing with a simple example, it generates:

```
const char * s = STRINGIFY(abc);
```

It may work with other compilers, for example the following g++ command line works:

```
g++ -D'STRINGIFY(X)=#X' -D'DEBUG=STRINGIFY(abc)' t.cc -E

# 1 "t.cc"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command line>"
# 1 "t.cc"

const char * s = "abc";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, at least under MSVC2012, you can't pass preprocessor definitions with arguments on the command line :(